# 10桁までのSelf-descriptive numberの求め方について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

各桁の数字がその桁の出現回数を表すような数を
Self-descriptive numberと呼びます。
（http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number）
以下のコードで、10桁までのSelf-descriptive numberを
求めようとしたのですが、
9桁、10桁のSelf-descriptive numberの算出に時間が
かかっています。
もっと高速に求める方法があれば、ご教示ください。

```
N = 10
(1..N).each{|b|
  (0..b - 1).to_a.repeated_permutation(b){|a|
    if a[0] > 0
      i = b - 1
      flag = true
      while i > -1 && flag
        if a.count(i) == a[i]
          i -= 1
        else
          flag = false
        end
      end
      p a.join.to_i if i == -1
    end
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

各桁の合計が目的の桁数を超える時点で計算を打ち切っています。

```
def sdn(len, x = [])
  a = []
  if x.size == len
    if (0..len - 1).all? {|i| x.count(i) == x[i]}
      a << x.join.to_i
    end
  elsif x.inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n } <= len
    s = x.size > 0 ? 0 : 1
    (s..len - 1).each { |n|
      a += sdn(len, x + [n])
    }
  end
  a
end

N = 10
(1..N).each{|b|
  sdn(b).each {|n| p n}
}
```

Comment: しらみつぶしに調べるのではなく、
h2so5さんのように、
「各桁の合計がlen以下のものに、
0〜len - 1を追加していく」やり方の方が
ずっと速いですね。

ちなみに、
s = x.size > 0 ? 0 : 1
はどこも使用しないので、不要ですね。

Comment: @Manyama sを使い忘れていたので修正しました。すこし速くなっているはずです。

Comment: 「0から始まることはない」ことを利用するのに、sを導入したわけですね。

Answer (score 1):

（コメントでコードを書くと上手く表示されないので、回答を使っています。）
h2so5さんのコードを用いて少しばかり高速化しました。

```
def sdn(len, l = 0, m = 0, x = [])
  a = []
  if l == len
    if (0..len - 1).all?{|i| x.count(i) == x[i]}
      a << x.join.to_i
    end
  elsif m <= len
    s = l > 0 ? 0 : 1
    (s..len - 1).each{|n| a += sdn(len, l + 1, m + n, x + [n])}
  end
  a
end

N = 10
(1..N).each{|b|
  sdn(b).each{|n| p n}
}
```